# IdentityServer4 on .Net Core2 with bearer - API not validating auth / custom policy handler

Tags: claims-based-identity, identityserver4, policy, bearer-token, .net-core-2.0

I try to setup an identity server 4 + API + web Scenario but can't get users authenticated in the api. Each component uses a separate Project within my VS solution. All Projects are on dotnetcore 2.0.

**Startup.cs Identity Server**

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
 services.AddCors();
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            })
            .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential() 
.AddExtensionGrantValidator<Extensions.ExtensionGrantValidator>()
            .AddExtensionGrantValidator<Extensions.NoSubjectExtensionGrantValidator>()
.AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);
```

**TestUsers.Users**

```
  public class TestUsers
    {
        public static List<IdentityServer4.Test.TestUser> Users = new List<IdentityServer4.Test.TestUser>
        {
            new IdentityServer4.Test.TestUser{SubjectId = "818727", Username = "alice", Password = "alice",
                Claims =
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "UserEditor"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Alice Smith"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "AliceSmith@email.com"),
                }
            },
            new IdentityServer4.Test.TestUser{SubjectId = "88421113", Username = "bob", Password = "bob",
                Claims =
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Root"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "UserEditor"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Bob Smith"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "BobSmith@email.com")
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Getting a indentityserver jwt bearer token works via http://localhost:2266/connect/token and it contains the relevant Information:

{
  ...
  ...
  "role": [
    "Root",
    "Admin",
    "UserEditor"
  ],
  "scope": [
    ...
  ],
  ...
}

However - on the API side authentication is not checked properly.

**API Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext...
    ...
    ...

    services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddJsonFormatters();

    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:2266";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ApiSecret = "secret";
            options.ApiName = "MyApi";
        });

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
        options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:44352")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });

    // custom policy attributes
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Root", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new Models.Policies.MyPolicyRequirement("Root")));
        options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new Models.Policies.MyPolicyRequirement("Admin")));
        options.AddPolicy("UserEdit", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new Models.Policies.MyPolicyRequirement("UserEdit")));
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, Models.Policies.MyPolicyHandler>();
    services.AddMvc();

    // add swagger
    ...
}
```

**The policy Validation** 
Controller/Actions are marked with the Authorize Attribute, e.g 
[Authorize(Policy = "Root")]
The Code of the policy handler is hit while Debugging.

```
public class MyPolicyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyPolicyRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyPolicyRequirement requirement)
    {
        if ( !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
            return Task.CompletedTask;


        if (context.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().HasClaim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role, requirement.Policy))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
}
```

The validation fails because the context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false, the objects identity has no Claims as well. 
Looks like something is missing in the Pipeline to convert my bearer authentication to an user identity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you call `App.UseAuthentication` in your pipeline?

Comment: Sorry - forgot that part. The Configure Part of the IdentityServer Startup contains:

    `app.UseIdentityServer();`

The Configure Part of the Startup.cs of the API:
`app.UseCors("default");
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();`

Comment: I meant the api pipeline

Comment: Yes, the Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ...) contains  
app.UseCors("default");  
app.UseAuthentication();  
app.UseMvc();

Comment: then I am out of ideas right now ;)

Comment: This is what the dubug log in the API Project Looks like when requesting a secured API method:  
  
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:1950/api/v1/admin/Mandator   
Authorization failed for user: (null). 
Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'. 
Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (). 
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged. 
Executed action CsmApi.Controllers.v1.Admin.MandatorController.Get (CsmApi) in 12279.2758ms

Comment: Added scheme to policies:
´  
options.AddPolicy("UserEdit", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddRequirements(new Models.Policies.MyPolicyRequirement("UserEdit"));
                    builder.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                });
`  
New log:  
Failed to validate the token ey..... Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateTokenReplay(System.String, System.Nullable`1<System.DateTime>, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters)'.

Comment: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was not authenticated. Failure message: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateTokenReplay(System.String, System.Nullable`1<System.DateTime>, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters)'.  
Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateTokenReplay(System.String, System.Nullable`1<System.DateTime>, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters)'.

Comment: That looks like some sort of version mismatch..maybe strip it down to the bare minimum and check the if the User object on the controller is set or not. Get those policies out of the way first,. And then maybe open an issue with the log data..

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem:
I had a reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (5.2.0-preview1) because of
some code to load the signing certificate.

If that package is enabled the Validation Fails.

I once started with validating the signing certificate of the token by myself so i needed that component but i guess all that will be handled automatically in the AddIdentityServerAuthentication part?

So the policy check was not the Problem. Thanks for asking me to start from base.